# How to Calculate Total Less Duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am attempting to create a formula that calculates deviations from a certain parameter threshold in hours. The parameters being recorded are water flow in gallons per minute and chemical addition. Each parameter is recorded every hour. If the parameter is below the parameter threshold it is considered a deviation. Deviations *are not* double counted: If both parameters are deviant in the same hour period then it only counts as one hour of deviation.

I have three columns set up. One is a date and time column (1/1/2016 1:00am, 1/1/2016 2:00am, etc.) and the other two are parameter columns. I have no problem setting up formulas for calculating hours of deviation for each parameter separately. My issue is setting up a formula that essentially sums both parameters deviations in hours without double counting time spans where both parameters are deviant.

I would appreciate any help that can be offered or suggestions for the right direction to go. So far I've attempted using IF and AND functions and some others but am unsure of the correct combination i need to use.

If anything needs to be clarified please let me know. Thanks.

- EDIT *

I couldn't get the table generator to work for me so here is an image of how the data is set up:

[image: Data Set Up]

This is an example of the formula in cell E3, which I use to tell whether a given parameter is deviant (essentially the same as cell G3):

```
=IF(B3>=127,"No",A3)
```

Here is the formula that counts the total water flow deviations in cell F3 (essentially the same as cell H3):

```
=COUNTIF(E3:E8,">0")
```

The result, as can be seen in the image above, is a total of 5 hrs of water flow deviations and 3 hrs of chemical addition deviations. However, because both parameters deviate during the same time period in certain instances, the total amount of deviant hours is 6. This is what I want a formula to calculate for me. Below is a unfinished bit of formula I've been working with, although it is woefully inadequate:

```
=IF(AND(E3:E8,G3:8)
```

My thought process was IF column E AND G are equal during the same time period, then count them as one hour of deviation. Obviously it's missing some things. I just can't seem to wrap my head around where to go next, or if I'm even heading in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will update the question.

Comment: Also please share your existing formula which already works for one parameter. That would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can e.g. subtract number of duplicates from the total number:
   `= F3 + H3 - COUNTIFS(B3:B8,"<127",C3:C8,"<368")`
2. Another approach can be to add a new column where you check whether any of the parameters fail, then simply count them as you did before:
   `=IF(and(B3>=127,C3>=368),"No",A3)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was definitely over thinking it!